# An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

**Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) on project FrescoJPADemo: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]**

1. JPADemo.java

   ```
   import javax.persistence.*;
   import frescojpa.Student;

   import java.util.*;

   public class JPADemo {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf =
         Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("$objectdb/students.odb");
     EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
     entityManager.getTransaction( ).begin( );
       try {
             Student student = new Student(1, "Ramesh");
             entityManager.persist(student);
             Student student1 = new Student(2, "John");
             entityManager.persist(student1);
             Student student2 = new Student(3, "Ali");
             entityManager.persist(student2);
             System.out.println(entityManager.find(Student.class,1).getStudentName());
             System.out.println(entityManager.find(Student.class,2).getStudentName());
             System.out.println(entityManager.find(Student.class,3).getStudentName());
                 entityManager.getTransaction( ).commit( );
           }
           finally {
               entityManager.close();
                     emf.close();
           } 
         }
     }
   ```

2.Student.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int studentRollNumber;
    private String studentName;

    public Student(int studentRollNumber, String studentName) {
        this.studentRollNumber = studentRollNumber;
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getStudentRollNumber() {
        return studentRollNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentRollNumber(int studentRollNumber) {
        this.studentRollNumber = studentRollNumber;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>FrescoJPADemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>FrescoJPADemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>objectdb</id>
            <name>ObjectDB Repository</name>
            <url>https://m2.objectdb.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.objectdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectdb</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>enhance</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>com.objectdb.Enhancer</mainClass>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>student.*</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>student.Main</mainClass>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

score.java

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

public class Score {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         EntityManagerFactory emf =
                    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("$objectdb/students.odb");
                EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


                // Find the number of Student objects in the database:
                Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Student p");
                System.out.println("Total Points: " + q1.getSingleResult());

          
                // Retrieve all the Student objects from the database:
                TypedQuery<Student> query =
                    em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Student p", Student.class);
                List<Student> results = query.getResultList();
                int count=0;
                for (Student p : results) {
                    String name=p.getStudentName();
                    if(name.equals("Ramesh") || name.equals("John") || name.equals("Ali")){
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                if(count>=3){
                    System.out.println("FS_SCORE:100%");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("FS_SCORE:0%");
                }

                // Close the database connection:
                em.close();
                emf.close();
    }

}
```

**Getting Score 0 Please help I am not able to understand what's wrong in that, It is hackerrank problem**

Comment: I think you are getting entityManager as null


entityManager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

Comment: Yes, it is for transaction begining. Anything wrong in that?